# Can an HTML tag's value attribute be used to store JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a simple random word generator and am trying to have a `<select>` drop-down determine the number of words to be displayed. My idea was to have the `<option>`'s value contain the variables I want to be parsed into my function. However, it doesn't read the variables as I'd hoped, like it does in the first div, and instead writes the literal values. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write this, but now I'm curious if I can even do it this way.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N988s/1/)

HTML:

```
<select id="wordCount" class="span2">
    <option value="word1">1 Words</option>
    <option value="word1+' '+word2">2 Words</option>
    <option value="word1+' '+word2+' '+word3">3 Words</option>
    <option value="word1+' '+word2+' '+word3+' '+word4">4 Words</option>
</select>
<input id="gen" type="submit" value="Generate">
<div id="wordBin"></div>
<div id="wordBin2"></div>
```

JavasSript:

```
$('#gen').click(function generateWords(){
    var wordCount = document.getElementById('wordCount').value;
    var wordbank = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor', 'apple', 'beer', 'potato'];
    var word1 = wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordbank.length)];
    var word2 = wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordbank.length)];
    var word3 = wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordbank.length)];
    var word4 = wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordbank.length)];
    var wordBin = document.getElementById('wordBin');
    var wordBin2 = document.getElementById('wordBin2');
    wordBin.innerHTML = word1+' '+word2+' '+word3+' '+word4;
    wordBin2.innerHTML = wordCount;
});
```

Comment: Sure, but it is a terrible idea and tears are sure to follow.

Comment: You could, but... then you would have to be evil.

Comment: @KevinB - +1. Let me just eval your statement. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend this at all, but what you're looking for is `eval`.  I've updated the fiddle with a simple change:

```
wordBin.innerHTML = word1+' '+word2+' '+word3+' '+word4;
```

to

```
wordBin.innerHTML = eval(wordCount);
```

and it works just like you want.  However, that's a ***TERRIBLE*** way to do things (just as you alluded to).  It would be much better if you stored a count in your values and looped through the count by appending the random word.  The real HTML/javascript would work like this:

**HTML:**

```html
<select id="wordCount" class="span2">
    <option value="1">1 Words</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2 Words</option>
    <option value="3">3 Words</option>
    <option value="4">4 Words</option>
</select>
<input id="gen" type="submit" value="Generate">
<div id="wordBin"></div>
<div id="wordBin2"></div>
```

**JS:**

```js
$('#gen').click(function generateWords() {
    var wordCount = document.getElementById('wordCount').value;
    var wordbank = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor', 'apple', 'beer', 'potato'];

    var finalMessage = "";
    for (i = 0; i < parseInt(wordCount, 10); i++) {
        if (i > 0) finalMessage += " ";
        finalMessage += wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordbank.length)];
    }

    var wordBin = document.getElementById('wordBin');
    var wordBin2 = document.getElementById('wordBin2');
    wordBin.innerHTML = finalMessage;
    wordBin2.innerHTML = wordCount;
});
```

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/N988s/2/

Comment: You should never use `eval()` unless your life depends on it.

Comment: @IbrahimAshShohail which is why I said it was a terrible idea :)

Comment: You can never emphasis this. And I would always hide the presence of such a method from beginners. If learn about it early, then tend to use it without releasing what bad things could this lead to. :)

Comment: Valid point.  Updated the post for emphasis on terrible, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
<select id="wordCount" class="span2">
  <option value="1">1 Word</option>
  <option value="2">2 Words</option>
  <option value="3">3 Words</option>
  <option value="4">4 Words</option>
</select>
<input id="gen" type="submit" value="Generate">
<div id="wordBin"></div>
<div id="wordBin2"></div>
```

Js:

```
var wordbank = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor', 'apple', 'beer', 'potato'];
$('#gen').click(function () {
    var wordCount = document.getElementById('wordCount').value;
    var wordBin = document.getElementById('wordBin');
    words = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        if (words != '') words += ' ';
        words += getRandomWord();
        wordBin.innerHTML = words;
    }
});
function getRandomWord() {
    return wordbank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordbank.length)];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N988s/3/

Comment: This could tweak more, I know.